# Reputation graph type

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-graph

When I go to my profile on SO I get a 'bar' type reputation graph.

When I go to network profile I get a 'cumulative' / 'line' type reputation graph.

Would it be possible to be able to switch graph types?

Comment: Should be tagged with [tag:reputation-graph] and [tag:profile] (I don't have the right to retag).

Comment: @casperOne: didn't know there were tags for it. tnx